# How do I find what index a True value is located at in an array contaning True and False values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have an np.array with True and False values in it. Something along the lines of this:

```
full=[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
    False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 
    False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False,
    False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

There is a true value at the 24th position. I know that

```
b = np.where(full)
```

will print out something like this

```
(array([24]),)
```

but I am only interested in the number 24. Assuming that this True value can be at any place in the full array and that there can even be more than one True value in full, how do I retrieve the numbers in b?

edit: Trying to be more specific. Basically I am trying to take the value from b and put it into another np.array. If I enter b into a 1d array like so:

oar[b]

because b is not a number it sends back an error.

Also, just to reiterate, full is a numpy array and can have all true, no true, or multiple true values.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about what you mean by "retrieve": the numbers are right there.  `b[0]` is an array containing the indices, and `b[0][0] == 24`.

Comment: Can there be multiple true values? how about zero true values?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `argmax(arr)` for the index of the first `True` value.

As pointed out by @Alok, if the result is zero you must then check if the first element of `arr` is `False`.

Comment: This should be qualified with "it assumes that there is at least one `True` value".

Comment: True. however you just need to further check if the value of the first item in `arr` is `False` and the job is done.

Comment: sometimes full is false everywhere

Comment: and you then return `None` or whatever NOT_FOUND value your method should return.

Comment: @DavidCarr it works for any number of true values (`argmax()` documentation is explicit about it returning the first index in case there are repeats).